# Sending line-level signal to two devices

Tags: mixing, monitoring, line-level

I want to send a line-level signal (coming out of a [DAC](https://jdslabs.com/product/atom-dac-plus/)) to 2 devices, both of which will be working at the same time. Can I split the line-level signal with a simple [Y splitter](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/YPP111--hosa-ypp-111-y-cable-1-4-inch-ts-to-dual-1-4-inch-tsf-6-inch)? The actual set up involves sending this signal to two "External in" channels in a PreSonus HP60.

Here's a simple wiring diagram with the idea.
[image]

Or would an ABY box/dedicated splitter box  be beneficial? Thanks!

Comment: By splitting it passively you might a have little drop in signal strength (and in some cases crosstalk) but I would try just it out and judge from there.

Comment: Why do you need to? I can't think of any reason to do this. You're trying to double-input to a device that already has per-headphone mixing. It just feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Please ask us about the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than how to implement your assumed solution.

Comment: He said in the text that 2 devices will be connected. The picture is just for reference, and shows only one device, but thats not what he is doing :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put some resistors here just to be on the safe side, like this:

```
L_IN1<------|2k|------+------<L_OUT
L_IN2<------|2k|------+

R_IN1<------|2k|------+------<R_OUT
R_IN2<------|2k|------+
```

Adding 2 resistors here is mainly for electrical protection of all 3 devices, but will not influence the sound itself.
Other than that its just smth that works :)